# How to get the drop down value into controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have a drop down in View and for select index change I am using Jquery like this

```
$(function () { 
    $('#IncidentObj').change(function () {          
        var selectedValue = $(this).val();      
        alert(selectedValue)     
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Index", "Operation")',
            type: 'GET',
            cache: false,
            data: { value: selectedValue },
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.success)
            }
        });
    });
});
```

How can I get the value of selectedvalue into controller?

Comment: Whats the signature of the `Index`method? Does it have a parameter named `value`?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the value to the Index action method within your Operation Controller you need to make sure your Index action method within your Operation Controller has a parameter named "value" like so:

```
public class OperationController{

public ActionResult Index(String value){

    // do stuff here with "value"
    ...
    ...
}

...
...

}
```

where the "String" type I specified for the method parameter "value", can be changed to Int, bool, ect.. to fit your needs.

The reason why the method parameter is named "value" and not something else is because in your ajax call you specified:

```
data: { value: selectedValue },
```